# Cambiar el la cadena resultado de una consulta directamente en la consulta

Tags: mysql, string, select

tengo una consulta que en una campo me debe arrojar los alguno de los siguientes valores:
**I** , **T** , **F** ó **R**

Es posible hacer que el resultado de la consulta no me arroje la letra **I** por ejemplo, sino que pueda cambiarla por la palabra **INVENTARIO**? y así mismo con las otras letras?

La cónsula es básica **(SELECT Estado FROM Tabla)** Pero el campo **Estado**, son solo las iniciales, y necesito convertirlas a la palabra completa,
debo aclarar que no puedo usar PHP para hacerlo, debo hacerlo directamente en la consulta MySQL.

Es posible hacerlo?
alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El camino básico es [CASE-WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case),

```
SELECT Estado 
CASE
    WHEN Estado = 'I' THEN "INVENTARIO"
    WHEN Estado = 'T' THEN "TOMATE"
    WHEN Estado = 'F' THEN "FIDEOS"
    WHEN Estado = 'R' THEN "RATONES"
    ELSE "N/A"
END 
FROM Tabla;
```

Comment: Mil gracias, esa era la respuesta que necesitaba.

Comment: @LeonardoRodriguezStoehr recuerda que, si una respuesta resolvió tu duda, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Así, otros sabrán cuál es la solución si tienen el mismo problema :)